# Accessing a grid from a different class

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How can I access a `Grid` control from a different class in code?

I need the same instance of the `Grid`.
And it doesn't seem to be possible to make `Grid` control shared.

Maybe I can somehow databind the entire contents of a `Grid`?

Edit:

Ok, here's a simplified example:

I have a simple window with a grid:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">

</Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to dynamically add some new elements to this grid, so from the same window class I would do something like this:

```
Public Class MainWindow 

Sub MySub()
    Dim NewElement As UIElement

    Me.MyGrid.Children.Add(NewElement)
End Sub

End Class
```

But how can I do this, if I wanted to add new element from outside of the window class? For example:

```
Class MyNewClass

Sub MySub()
    Dim NewElement As UIElement

    MainWindow.MyGrid.Children.Add(NewElement)
End Sub

End Class
```

This doesn't work because it requires an new instance, but I need to access the same original instance.

Comment: Creating an object of that class an access the control through it?

Comment: Try providing some context to your question... what `Grid`, what class? I have no idea what you want, although in WPF, we don't generally *access UI elements*. I suggest that you either improve your question, or investigate data binding.

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness. Added more information and examples to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data grid as a parameter to the class.  Below class is based on your example.

```
Class MyNewClass

    Sub MySub(MyGrid as DataGrid)

       Dim NewElement As UIElement
       MyGrid.Children.Add(NewElement)

    End Sub

End Class
```